# map subdomain to different applications running on same IP same port distingushed by path

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy, tomcat7, reverse-proxy

I have 3 applications(one web application,2 angular apps) running on same ec2 instance on same port(8080)
Paths to apps are

1. http://53.233.23.12:8080/Abc
2. http://53.233.23.12:8080/Xyz
3. http://53.233.23.12:8080/Pqr

I am using Nginx for redirection in server
My nginx.conf file looks like this`

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
   include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
      }
http{
       log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] 
    "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

index   index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    server_name www.listmydebt.com listmydebt.com;
    return 301  http://listmydebt.com:8080/Abc;


    # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }

 }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name admin.listmydebt.com;
        return 301  http://listmydebt.com:8080/Xyz;
    }
     server {
        listen 80;
        server_name partner.listmydebt.com;
        return 301  http://listmydebt.com:8080/Pqr;
    }
  }
```

All domain and subdomains( listmydebt.com, admin.listmydebt.com , partner.listmydebt.com) pointing to same IP address(53.233.23.12).
My Nginx is running on port 80 and tomcat server in which my applications are deplyed running on port 8080

When I put listmydebt.com its redirecting to http://listmydebt.com:8080/Abc and browser url changed(http://listmydebt.com:8080/Abc). But what I want is the url on browser should remain same as listmydebt.com but it should show the redirected url content.same happening for subdomains as well.

Please help me out .If any additional info is required please mention.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are describing the function of a reverse proxy. Investigate the [`proxy_pass` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

Comment: @Satyajit Did you get a solution finally?

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use docker swarm, or at least run the applications as several dockers in several ports.
Then you can easily map the ports on subdomains with an ansible playbook.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).